# How to calculate the co-ordinates of a quadrilateral knowing the side lengths

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, quadrilateral

Hi I've come across a mathematical problem, which I can't seem to solve with my limited geometry and trigonometry knowledge.

I need to draw a quadrilateral (may not be rectangle always). To draw this quadrilateral, I need to know the coordinate points of each corner. All I know is the length of all four sides and co-ordinates for top side (100,0) and (600,0).

[image]

There is no guarantee on the orientation of the box. At any given point of time only one side can be a straight (0 degrees) or perpendicular (90 degrees) side. So the sides are not 90 degrees to each other.

Any help? This seems like it should be easy, but it is really stumping me.

Comment: Do you at least know that the quad is convex? Otherwise there can be several differently-shaped ones with the same of side lengths.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It appears that is one such quadrilateral in the first quadrant and another in the third. I scaled the sides to $10,12,6,13$.

Comment: Thanks Quasar for your comment. Is there any way to achieve this without drawing circles? Because I need to get these co-ordinates Programmatically (in HTML5) to plot the quadrilateral.